# Generating appropriate axis labels after log transform

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

The scatterplot before the transform is like this:
[image]

After the log transform:
[image]

I cannot figure out how to put the ytick labels of the before-transform-plot to after-transform plot but still keep the log transform. Here is the code I tried:

```py
plt.scatter(data=diamonds, x='carat', y='price')
tick_labels = [0, 2500, 5000, 7500, 10000, 12500, 15000, 17500, 20000]
plt.yscale('log')
plt.yticks(tick_labels);
```

How do I make my vis more interpretable?

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the formatter as the scalar ticker while adjusting ticks with visible labels. You can see the example below.

```
import matplotlib.ticker 
# rest of your code
...
# get the current axes
ax = plt.gca()
#  y is log scaled 
ax.set_yscale('log')
# visible y labels
tick_labels = [0, 2500, 5000, 7500, 10000, 12500, 15000, 17500, 20000]
# set visible y labels
ax.set_yticks(tick_labels)
# adjust the formatter to be scalar
ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter())
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it is saying `t` is not defined I thought you meant `tick_labels` but it if I put `x.set_yticks(tick_labels)` it gave me the same problem

Comment: I corrected it, please try with `ax.set_yticks(tick_labels)`.

Comment: I already tried, giving me the same problem > Clustering all my point figures to the top of the plot

Comment: @BexTuychiev  Well, that's where they belong in log plot. What did you expect?

Comment: Before I added the xticks, the log function was working as expected, I just wanted to the xticks more interpretable